# Efficient way to apply multiple Boolean mask to set values in a column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

I have several expressions that select certain rows in a data frame (`df`) and return multiple Boolean arrays, masks if you like. I want to add a new column to this data frame and fill it with trivial integers ("membership" indicators) based on these masks. In the most straightforward approach I would use this code:

```
df.assign(membership=3)
df[mask1].membership = 0
df[mask2].membership = 1
df[mask3].membership = 2
```

This should yield a column (`df["membership"]`) as follows:

```
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
5    3
Name: membership, dtype: int64
```

The masks are created by function (using additional columns from the data frame to create the output) as a dictionary, which looks like this:

```
maskDict = {0:mask1, 1:mask2, 2:mask3}
```

where `mask(1..3)` are arrays of equal size containing `[True,False,...]` etc.

I am aware that there might not be a need to improve the code. However, when comparing more conditions I will end up with more Boolean arrays in the dictionary.

An in-place solution that applies the function to data frame and sets these values would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
df["membership"] = np.select([mask1, mask2, mask3], [0,1,2], default=3)
```

If input is `dict`:

```
df["membership1"] = np.select(list(maskDict.values()), list(maskDict.keys()), default=3)
```

Comment: Brilliant. Exactly something along these lines. Thank you!